# Unprotect sheet and Protect sheet 2 times continuously

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 sheets:Sheet1 and Sheet2. With Sheet 2, I locked it with password:"abc". In Sheet1, I created a Button(Form Control) , assign marco below:

```
Sub Test()
Sheet2.Unprotect "abc"
Sheet2.Protect "abc"
Sheet2.Unprotect "abc"
Sheet2.Protect "abc"
End Sub
```

When I click the Button in Sheet1, Sheet2 activated.Please explain this.

Comment: Some extra information:  Problem does not occur if procedure is just manually invoked (Macro Run) while `Sheet1` is active.  Problem does not occur if procedure is invoked from an ActiveX button.  The `Worksheet_Activate` event for `Sheet2` is not fired.  A `MsgBox Activesheet.Name` **prior** to the second `Unprotect` returns `Sheet1`, but a `MsgBox Activesheet.Name` **after** that statement returns `Sheet2`.

Comment: The interesting thing is that it only happens with 2 times, 4 times, 6 times ... With 1, 3, 5 times ... the activesheet is still sheet1.

Comment: Very interesting - as you say, the 3rd `Unprotect` is actually switching it back to `Sheet1`.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? I can't duplicate this at all (Excel 2010).

Comment: I use Office 2013.

Comment: @Ambie My testing was also done on Office 2013 Professional.  But I have just tested it on my personal laptop running Office Home and Business 2016, and that also causes the issue.

Comment: @YowE3K, thanks. It's an odd one all right. Whatever I try I can't reproduce this.

Comment: @Ambie I was thinking the problem didn't exist, until I did **exactly** what was in the question - i.e. the procedure has to be called from a Form Control button, not from an ActiveX one, and not just running the macro manually. (I'm hoping someone who understands the difference between Form Controls and ActiveX will have a look at the question sometime!) It's so weird it could well be something introduced in an update, so it won't surprise me if Excel 2010 isn't affected. (I think I have a **really** old laptop at home, so I might dig it out and see what it does - it probably has Excel 2003.)

Comment: @YowE3K, yeah it'd be interesting to hear. I've done an exact copy of what was in the question but still no joy.

Comment: @Ambie Tried in Excel 2003 - couldn't replicate the issue.  So it appears it may be a "bug" ("feature"?) introduced in Excel 2013.

Comment: What happens if you use worksheets("Sheet2").Unprotect "abc"  (or whatever sheet2 is called) instead? Is this an affect of using the sheets program name rather than index?

Comment: @HarassedDad I tried that also, and there is no difference in the behaviour.

Comment: Things like this are why I like to be overly explicit in the code I write - for example, setting the activesheet as ws1 (so wherever the button is located), then at the end of the code, putting in a ws1.activate - so I know where I end is where I started.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a minor bug. I just tested it & for me it's happening only in pair iterations. That is, if I iterate three times, I get just a fast screen update, but I stay in Sheet1. HOWEVER, when I go pairs, it switches to Sheet2.

I would recommend to do the following:

```
Dim WSh As Worksheet
Set WSh = Sheet2

For i = 1 To 6
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    WSh.Unprotect "abc"
    WSh.Protect "abc"
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```